# Spring mqtt integration SubscribeYou

Tags: spring-integration

i am creating a webapp in spring Maven with PAHO mqtt. and there are two ways to implement mqtt, one is Spring Mqtt Integration and second is a general way to create a connection object and connect/disconnect but what is the difference between them how much convenient and Reliable they are.

right now i am implementing subscribe with Spring Mqtt Integration but can't understand it can anyone please suggest some good easy tutorial.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

See the [Spring Integration MQTT Sample Spring Boot App](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/mqtt).

Reads from `stdIn` sends the data over MQTT, receives the data and logs it.

```
// publisher

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttOutFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin(),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
            .transform(p -> p + " sent to MQTT")
            .handle(mqttOutbound())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageHandler mqttOutbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("siSamplePublisher", mqttClientFactory());
    messageHandler.setAsync(true);
    messageHandler.setDefaultTopic("siSampleTopic");
    return messageHandler;
}

// consumer

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
            .transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT")
            .handle(logger())
            .get();
}

private LoggingHandler logger() {
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("siSample");
    return loggingHandler;
}

@Bean
public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("siSampleConsumer",
            mqttClientFactory(), "siSampleTopic");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    return adapter;
}
```